# Implicit conversion isn't working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make an implicit conversion and it works only with one argument, for example, if I leave only `unsigned int` it works otherwise it doesn't. What is happening?

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(unsigned int, const std::string&) {}
};

class Bar
{
public:
    void insertFoo(const Foo& foo)
    {

    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Bar bar;
    bar.insertFoo(100, std::string(""));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to copy-list-initialize `foo`, then you need braced-init-list, `bar.insertFoo( { 100, std::string("") } );`

Comment: Oh gosh, so silly. Thanks @PiotrS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertFoo()` takes a single argument, but you're passing it two. You can initialize from a braced initializer list like this:

```
bar.insertFoo( {100, std::string("")} );
```

This will create a temporary `Foo` with arguments `100` and `std::string("")`

You can also do it with `std::string`:

```
bar.insertFoo( {100, {}} );
```